# Syncing camera with other signals

Tags: sensors, cameras

I am not sure if this is the best place to ask this question, but hopefully someone here can give me some advice. I have a device hooked up to a data acquisition system that can provide sync out signal and record sync in signals. I need to synchronize my recordings with this device to a video feed. I am having trouble finding a camera that can provide a sync signal or any other good way to accomplish this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cameras that support syncing will probably do so via an external signal. Google "genlock" or "timecode sync" or "external trigger" to get started.  For instance, [here's a link](https://www.ptgrey.com/KB/10250) to external trigger modes for Point Grey cameras whose image sensors a lot of research roboticists use.

For the sync signal, if the sync out on the DAQ is not sufficient, google "sync generator". You should get relevant hits from the video & audio recording as well as electronics test worlds.